# Will VS2015 Development for Xamarin be affected when VS2017 or VS2107 RC install

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I m currently learning to develop Cross platform app on VS2015 Community version with Xamarin.

Understand there is a new release VS2017. But I am not sure what to do as I read some warnings when using VS2017 RC for Xamarin:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/visualstudio-2017-rc/

please note that currently, installing Xamarin to Visual Studio 2017 RC will uninstall any earlier versions of Xamarin installed into Visual Studio 2015/2013.

I would like to know:

1) How To identify which version is VS2017 or VS2017 RC? Are they the same?
2) After installing VS2017, Can I still use VS2015 Community version? Will installing VS2017 cause the version of Xamarin be removed for VS2015?

**update**

Some beginner questions on Cross-platform development with VS2017 Community on Windows 10 PC. I will start it on a new win10 PC with no VS.

After Installing VS2017 Community version.

1) Do I need to install Xamarin Unified Installer

Download the Xamarin Unified Installer(http://www.xamarin.com/Download)

will it install the following in Win10 PC

a) Xamarin.Android
b) Xamarin.iOS
c) all the required tools (SDK/JDK)

2) Do I need to open VS2017 in Programs and features in Control Panel by right click it and do setting on Cross Platform Mobile Development like selecting (C#/.Net(Xamarin v4...)

Please provide reference if there is any tutorial on installing VS2017 Community version for Xamarin.

Thanks

Comment: As far as #2 is concerned, you can install VS2017 Community version and still use VS 2015 Community version. When you install VS2017 you will need to make a choice if you want to include the Xamarin tools. You can install them at any point after the VS2017 install.

Comment: Do not use the VS2017RC either use the release VS 2017 or the preview version https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/

Comment: Very likely it should have been fixed in VS2017 RTM or a later Update. VS releases can safely run side by side.

Comment: @all, appreciate your help. I have a update as above.